# VB Equivalent of CSharpFormattingOptions

Tags: vb.net, roslyn

Where is the VB Equivalent of CSharpFormattingOptions, I am trying to control Formatter.Format but I don't see any VB version like the following

```
Dim CSharpOptions As OptionSet = workspace.Options
CSharpOptions = CSharpOptions.WithChangedOption(CSharpFormattingOptions.NewLinesForBracesInMethods, True)
CSharpOptions = CSharpOptions.WithChangedOption(CSharpFormattingOptions.NewLinesForBracesInProperties, True)
```

Comment: VB has no such syntax.

Comment: So how do I control what the Formatter does like I can in C# and C++ or is there a way to get NormalizeWhiteSpace  to just deal with spaces and leave new lines alone? I am trying to preserve Formatting everything I found is very aggressive making code hard to read.

Comment: VB has no such options (just like it doesn't in VS)

Comment: I think that explains why I can't do a .NormalizeWhiteSpace on a document in my codefix, I need to do it on small code sections.